# understanding EAGLView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking at the EAGLView files from the apple iphone sample code and I am trying to understand how EAGLViewDelegate protocol works.

Question:

How does this `didResizeEAGLSurfaceForView` function get called? I don't see any implementation of it?

EAGLView.h

```
@protocol EAGLViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) didResizeEAGLSurfaceForView:(EAGLView*)view; 
   //Called whenever the EAGL surface has been resized
@end

@interface EAGLView : UIView
{
  @private
    id<EAGLViewDelegate>    _delegate;
}


@property(assign) id<EAGLViewDelegate> delegate;
```

---

EAGLView.m

```
@implementation EAGLView

@synthesize 
    delegate      = _delegate, 

//......
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to the CrashLanding, GLGravity, or GLPaint samples, as those samples are the only ones I can find with this protocol.  The didResizeEAGLSurfaceForView: method is called in the MyEAGLView -_createSurface method.  However, the method is not implemented anywhere, because the delegate is not set for the MyEAGLView in any of those samples.

So no, I don't think you're missing anything.  This looks like vestigial code.